# How to close a bottom sheet

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, bottom-sheet, react-navigation-bottom-tab, touchableopacity

I am new to react native and I was trying to use the bottom sheet. For some reason, I cannot close the bottom sheet when the cross icon is pressed. Below is the code

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet from 'react-native-simple-bottom-sheet';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

const BottomSheet1 = () => {
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef();

  const closeBottomSheet = () => {
    if (bottomSheetRef.current) {
      bottomSheetRef.current.togglePanel();
    }
  };


  const data = [
    { label: '2D Test' },
    { label: '2D Testing 2' },
    { label: '2D Testing 3' },
    { label: '2D Testing 1' },
    { label: '2D Testzaffar' },
    { label: '2D TestZaffar' },
  ];

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item}>
        <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>{item.label}</Text>
          <MaterialIcons name="keyboard-arrow-down" size={24} color="#555" style={styles.arrowIcon} />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BottomSheet ref={bottomSheetRef} onClose={closeBottomSheet} maxHeight={500}>
        <View style={styles.bottomSheet}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => bottomSheetRef.current.close()} style={styles.closeIcon}>
            <MaterialIcons name="close" size={24} color="#555" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={[styles.title, { fontFamily: 'Montserrat' }]}>Truminds</Text>
            <Text style={styles.create}>+ Create Subspace</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.separator} />
          <FlatList
            style={styles.list}
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.label}
            maxHeight={250}
          />
        </View>
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: 0,
    paddingTop: 48,
  },
  itemContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginBottom: 17,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 800,
  },
  create: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: 600,
    color: '#0F8D48',
  },
  bottomSheet: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    marginTop: -20,
  },
  separator: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  list: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  listItem: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingVertical: 10,
  },
  labelContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 600,
  },
  arrowIcon: {
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  listArrowIcon: {
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  closeIcon: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 5,
    right: 15,
  },
});

export default BottomSheet1;
```

There's no response on clicking the close icon. Only when I click the top portion of the bottom sheet, it appears to go down but pop back upwards again.

Comment: The onClose callback of the BottomSheet component is linked to the function closeBottomSheet that is toggling the BottomSheet component. That's why it's reopening again. Try to remove that onClose callback and assign the closeBottomSheet function to the onPress callback of the <TouchableOpacity /> containing your close icon

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine now. But what I want is that the sheet should close on clicking the close icon. But when I'm clicking on it there's no response. I have to press on the top portion of the sheet to close it.

Comment: Okay fixed this. Apparently there was an issue with the styling of the close icon. position: 'absolute' was causing the issue